# Using Yahoo map and OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, yahoo

Trying to get this code working with one OSM layer and one yahoo layer for OpenLayers 3 and Geoserver. Anyone have any idea where the problem migth be?

If I remove everything with the yahoo map, it all works fine (with only OSM map), however, i need the yahoo map to work as well.  Please help :)

P.s. src="http://api.maps.yahoo.com/ajaxymap?v=3.0&appid=euzuro-openlayers" script is loaded at the top, do not know if this might be the problem? Wrong script?

Open street Maps and Geoserver

```
<script>
//Defining projections
    var geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

//Defining bounds    
    var world = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180, -89, 180, 89).transform(
        geographic, mercator
    );
//Defining map center    
    var lund_center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(13.19, 55.71).transform(
        geographic, mercator
    );

    var options = {
        projection: mercator,
        displayProjection: geographic,
        units: "m",
        maxExtent: world,
        maxResolution: 156543.0399,

    };


//Defining main variables  
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", options, { controls: [] });


    var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    var yLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Yahoo("Hybrid");


    map.addLayer(osm);
    map.addLayer(yLayer);

//List of layers 

    var roads_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "Roads",
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
        {
            layers: "lu:vagar_alla",
            transparent: "true",
            format: "image/png"
        },
        {isBaseLayer: false, visibility: true}
    );
    map.addLayer(roads_wms);


    var raildroads_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "Railroads",
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
        {
            layers: "lu:railroads",
            transparent: "true",
            format: "image/png"
        },
        {isBaseLayer: false, visibility: true}
    );
    map.addLayer(raildroads_wms);


    var buildings_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "Official buildings",
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
        {
            layers: "lu:bygg_off",
            transparent: "true",
            format: "image/png"
        },
        {isBaseLayer: false, visibility: true}
    );
    map.addLayer(buildings_wms);

    var other_build_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "Other buildings",
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
        {
            layers: "lu:bygg_ovr",
            transparent: "true",
            format: "image/png"
        },
        {isBaseLayer: false, visibility: true}
    );
    map.addLayer(other_build_wms);




   ///////////////////////////////////////




//Map center and zoom
    map.setCenter(lund_center, 14);

//List of controls    
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults());          
    map.addControl(new  OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine());

//Coordinates of mouse position
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition()); 






</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe Yahoo maps closed shop.

http://api.maps.yahoo.com fails a DNS check so the server is down.

Comment: Yeah, I found out later as well...